# How to attach a compound component when using React forward ref (property does not exist on forwardRefExoticComponent)

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have a Panel component that optionally allows the user to use compound components. The panel has a default header that contains the close functionality (button) and the main reason I did this is was to give the user the option to use a custom header with their own button and whatever else they would like, so I opted to use compound components and to allow the Panel component to check for the existence of the component in its children and if so, it will not use the default header. I have it all working but I can't seem to figure out how to get the Typescript error to clear.

Below is the code pertaining to Typescript and the error I'm getting. I also linked to a sandbox with the working code with errors.

***I have tried tons of variations from Google searches and in a days time cannot find the solution.***

Sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/panel-513yq?file=/src/Panel/Panel.tsx:510-4061

***App.js:***

```
export default function App() {
  const [open, setOpen] = React.useState(false);

  const handleClose = () => {
    setOpen(false);
  };

  const handleOpen = () => {
    setOpen(true);
  };

  return (
    <div id="page" data-test-id="component-app">
      <header id="header">
        <button onClick={handleOpen}>Open</button>
      </header>
      <main id="main">
        <Panel open={open} onClosed={handleClose} renderPortal={true}>
          <Panel.Header>
            <div>
              <button onClick={handleClose}>Close</button>
            </div>
          </Panel.Header>
          <Panel.Content>Panel Content</Panel.Content>
        </Panel>
      </main>
    </div>
  );
}
```

***Panel Component:***

```
interface ModalPropsComposition {
  Header?: React.FC<PanelHeaderProps>;
  Content?: React.FC<PanelContentProps>;
}

export interface PanelProps
  extends React.HTMLAttributes<HTMLDivElement>,
    ModalPropsComposition {
  open: boolean;
  position?: string;
  renderPortal?: boolean;

  // Lifecycle callbacks
  onClose?: () => void;
  onClosed?: () => void;
  onOpen?: () => void;
  onOpened?: () => void;
}

/**
 * @Codeannex UI React: Panel Component
 *
 * Panel Component
 */
const _Panel = ({
  children,
  open,
  renderPortal,
  onClose,
  onClosed,
  onOpen,
  onOpened
}: PanelProps & { forwardedRef: React.Ref<HTMLDivElement> }): JSX.Element => {
  // panel code...
};

export const Panel = React.forwardRef(
  (props: PanelProps, ref: React.Ref<HTMLDivElement>): JSX.Element => {
    return <_Panel {...props} forwardedRef={ref} data-testid={PANEL_TEST_ID} />;
  }
);

Panel.Header = PanelHeader;
Panel.Content = PanelContent;
```

***Error:***

[image]

Comment: If you just want the error to clear, do `export const Panel: any` in Panel.tsx, the error is pretty much clear, by doing `Panel.Content = PanelContent` and `PanelHeader = PanelHeader` typescript complains since the properties Content and Header are custom and don't exist on the default forwardRef type.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

By doing in Panel.tsx

```js
Panel.Content = PanelContent;
Panel.Header = PanelHeader
```

typescript complains since the properties Content and Header are custom and don't exist on the base forwardRef type.

To fix it declare a custom interface that extends forwardRef base type and add your custom properties Header and Content:

```js
interface IPanel
  extends React.ForwardRefExoticComponent<
    PanelProps & React.RefAttributes<HTMLDivElement>
  > {
  Header: typeof PanelHeader;
  Content: typeof PanelContent;
}
```

and use it like this:

```js
const forwardRef = React.forwardRef<HTMLDivElement, PanelProps>(
  (props, ref): JSX.Element => {
    return (
      <PanelComponent
        {...props}
        forwardedRef={ref}
        data-testid={PANEL_TEST_ID}
      />
    );
  }
);

export const Panel = {
  ...forwardRef,
  Header: PanelHeader,
  Content: PanelContent
} as IPanel;
```

Or... just do `export const Panel: any` but you lose type checking by doing this

[Working CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/panel-forked-sw0uf?file=/src/App.tsx:523-785) forked from yours.

Comment: Thank you. However every library I have used in the past has not forced the developer to run that check Panel.Header &&. I would like to find a way to maintain the common patterns used when using compound components.

Comment: @Aaron updated the answer and the CodeSandbox so you no longer need to run the check.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer. This answer was very helpful.

Answer (score 10):

You can fix this error by using [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign). This works because Object.assign is typed as `assign<T, U>(target: T, source: U): T & U;`, so the types T and U can be [inferred](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-inference.html#contextual-typing), and the return type becomes a mix of the forwardRef exotic component type and the object with `Header` and `Content` properties.

```
export const Panel = Object.assign(
  React.forwardRef(
    (props: PanelProps, ref: React.Ref<HTMLDivElement>): JSX.Element => {
      return (
        <PanelComponent
          {...props}
          forwardedRef={ref}
          data-testid={PANEL_TEST_ID}
        />
      );
    }
  ),
  {
    Header: PanelHeader,
    Content: PanelContent
  }
);
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer. This answer was very helpful.